# Why errors appear at Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, url, uri, protocols

**Objective** 
Add (uri, url) with port.

```
 # Help for carlos-romero   
 # https://stackoverflow.com

 # Help for mu-is-too-short
 # https://stackoverflow.com

require 'uri'
require 'socket'

url = 'file://C://'

 class Class1
    def fileProtocol( url )
        uri = URI(url) if scheme = uri.scheme
      puts fileProtocol(url)
    end
  end

 class Class2
     def fileProtocolPort( server )
         server = TCPServer.open(8080)
           for i in  0..5
           client = server.accept
             client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
            client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
            client.close
            end
            end
            end
```

**ruby show this errors**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       2: from main.rb:7:in `<main>'
>       1: from main.rb:7:in`open'
>   main.rb:7:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for nil port 8080 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

So, what does that mean this error? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems there. In your method `fileProtocol` it seems like you are setting the value of `uri` with an inline if (`do X if condition`), so that `end` immediately following the `if` is unnecessary. Also, the `=` should be `==`

I believe you want something like this:

```
def fileProtocol( url , server ) 
   uri = URI(url, server) if scheme == uri.scheme  
   [url, server]
end

puts fileProtocol(url, server)
```

EDIT: Also, as @muistooshort pointed in the comments, the return value of the method (its last line) should wrap any multiple values you want to return in an array.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting '=' url, server

Comment: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end puts fileProtocol(url)

Comment: I think you want `[url, server]` at the end of the method, Ruby doesn't really let you return multiple values, you explicitly return an array and then deconstruct it during the assignment.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll see what I can do. ^^